# how to get a set with un-containable values in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala, and here is the question, below is my set

```
val set1 = Set("hello world, this is scala new", "hello world, this is scala", "hello world, this is", "hello apple")
```

and I want to have results like below shows

```
val set2 = Set("hello world, this is scala new", "hello apple")
```

since  "hello world, this is scala", "hello world, this is" all contained in "hello world, this is scala new", so I would like to remove them in set2, how to achieve this in scala?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: very dumb way... I compare one by one, if one element that has no other keys contains it, it will be added in the results

Comment: Well... isn't this an use case for Trie... build a Trie and then just pick the leaf nodes ?

Comment: Yeah, use Trie to build, but I saw the answer below, which is quite elegant and simple than mine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val set2 = set1.filterNot(s1 => set1.exists(s2 => s2.contains(s1) && s1 != s2))
```